# InstanceApp can not access from feature to feature module resources in java code

Tags: android, android-resources, android-instant-apps

I do not understand what exactly happens, but it seems when I want to access a resource in a feature module, when the resource also is located in that feature module, then the **InstanceApp** always looks for the resource in the base module (or maybe somewhere else). To make this work I can move the resource from feature module into the base and access those resources with the base module package name: **com.module.base.R.** Now the question is why **de.module.feature.R** or just **R** can't retrieve the respective resource at runtime, when it is working properly for **XML** usages.

EDIT 1: I am also using multidex can this be a problem?
ANSWER 1: Disabling of multidexing didn't help.

Comment: When you say it can't retrieve the resource at runtime, do you mean it throws a ResourceNotFoundException?

Comment: @Jichao exactly. But Android Studio and the installed app do not complain about this. I have also disabled multidexing from the project, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you file a bug, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: There have been reports of this created at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64100568 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67049756

Comment: @PragatiSingh Correct, this is reported by me :)

Answer (score 1):

The latest build-tools have been patched in with a fix for this issue.

- Please update your Android SDK Build-Tools to 27.0.2 version.
- Ensure you are on Android Studio 3.0.1 or newer.

**Note**: The [Google issue tracker post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64100568#comment6) regarding the Android Instant Application error crash has also been updated.